How can we skip first and last row of text file and create Dataframe using Pyspark?
I want to create Dataframe using text file - customer_{yyyyMMdd}.txt
Text file contains following type of data.
customer_20240716.txt|16-July-2024|TimeStamp
Rohan|235688|....
Akash|356854|....
.
.
.
.
RowCount|2500

For column mapping I will create Schema, but how can we skip first and last row while creating Data frame out of it using Pyspark?
I am using Spark 2.4.8.7

This question is similar to: Remove first and last row from the text file in pyspark. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I added a [generic] answer in the similar question that I linked. If you want to use the pandas method for your specific txt file, you can start with pandasDF = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep="|", header=None).iloc[1:-1]

Thanks, by using pandas it solves problem
